# Django Lambda with Microservices, Breaking Django Project in Lambda functions

Tags: django, django-models, aws-lambda, microservices, serverless

I've just started to implement serverless architecture using Django and AWS lambda and It's working perfectly fine now. My project consist of two apps **user_onboarding** and **user_training** and structure is as follows :

```
MainApp
- user_onboarding
  - models.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
- user_training
  - models.py
  - urls.py
  - views.py
- MainApp
  - urls.py
  - settings.py
  - wsgi.py
- manage.py
- lambda_handler.py
- serverless.yml
```

model/s are shared between both the apps, contains one to many, Foreign Key relations and working perfectly fine on Lambda. now, I want to split the apps into two different lambda functions.
i.e. user_onboarding in seperate lambda function and user_training in seperate lambda function.
what will be the best approach to achieve this?

My Questions while I was thinking of it:

1. how my models are going to be shared with lambda functions? does lambda layers is the best option?

> i) I've tried making layers of both the apps's models like this structure:

````
 ```
   > python/user_onboarding_models/models.py
   > python/user_training_models/models.py
 ```
````

> and when I tried to import models so that I can use to query in ORM like this : from user_onboarding_models.models import *. It gives me error - **RuntimeError: Model class user_onboarding_models.models.xxx doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS**  so can we share our models like this in layers? Is there any other way to do it?

2. In this structure, where will be my settings.py reside? this too in layers? or it will be in both the lambda functions?
3. How am I going to handle the migrations if I store models.py in layers?
4. how to achieve database connection for both lambda function as the project is now split?

My main motto is I want to use DRF to create API and for that I will use serializers with Models, so I badly want models to be accessible.

Please let me know if anyone needs some more detail on this to help you understand my problem.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: 1. You have to serve your models in a separate django application, and make that downloadable by your other apps via pip. 2. Both functions 3. As shared in #1 your migrations will be in the separate application (where your models are) so no conflicts there for the apps. 4. your models are the abstraction to connect to the database, so as long you properly setup #1, #2 and #3, both lambdas can connect to the database using the models found in the common django app you have in #1

Comment: Hi @bdbd, Thank you for the response. I did exactly the same and the architecture seems to be working as expected. I ran into one problem though. my layer of required libraries going out of size. I've tried splitting up the libraries into multiple layers but seems the libraries from both the layers not able to access each other. so every time I get "No module named xxxx". Is there any solution to this?? tia

Comment: Hi! How exactly was it split?

Comment: to divide libraries in two folders and upload them separately in two layers.
also, just a thought, can we use EFS instead of layers for our libraries? do we need EC2 instance for that?